# How to find $k$ in a $f(x)=g(x)$ type of equation if the discriminant is equal to $4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had this in one of my pre-tests and I don't remember learning anything like it in class... I searched on the internet how to solve $k$ in that specific situation, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

**It goes like this:**

> $$f(x)=(x-1)^2+k $$
> and
> $$g(x)=2x-4$$
> If the discriminant of the system $f(x)=g(x)$ is equal to $4$, determine the possible value(s) of $k$.

If you could help me understand what are the steps to find the possible value(s) of $k$ it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system $f(x)=g(x)$ is equivalent to the quadratic equation
$$x^2+k+5=0,$$
with discriminant $-4(k+5)=-4k-20$, which is equal to $4$ if $k=-6$.

Comment: Thank you very much!